# What are physical effects that could be employed to emulate this system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, optics, forces, energy

This is a simple system consisting of a tree of numbers such as `((1 2 (3 4)) (2 6) 1 6)` and a rule of application, that states that a tree A applied to B is a copy of A, where every number matching its own deepness on that tree is replaced by a copy of B. For example, that sequence applied to "9" is `(1 9 (3 4)) (10 6) 10 6`. The numbers replaced by 9 were those matching how deeply nested they were - for example, "2" in (2 6) because it has 2 enclosing parenthesis.

This can be obviously done with computers, but this would involve lots of redundant electron mashing in a physical level. I'm looking for a physical system that implements this operation as effectively as possible. Do you guys have an idea where I can start looking for it?

Note: I'm not sure if this question fits here but I don't know where else to ask.

Comment: This seems wayyyy too contrived to match nature. There aren't many physical systems that match tree structures I can think of (and certainly there are no self-similar hierarchies more than a few levels deep), and the added requirement of having the data stored in the node reference the tree structure itself - that's just asking for too much. *Maybe* biology could cook up something where tree depth corresponds to a signalling chemical concentration, but that's still a huge stretch.

Comment: It doesn't have to be perfect, but how close can we get? For example, it could be a string of registers instead of not a tree, no problems. Which kind of register could make it easier to perform the substitution operation, though? How? Does quantum computing help here? How? Etc. Any thoughtful input is valid. Just anything superior to emulating with computers, which should exist.